# query to select count of records for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

sorry for this newbie question ... im trying to get number of rows per year of my table..... this is my try:

```
select count(*)
from tbl_fact
where stat = 1 and id = 16
group by (year(fact_date))
go
```

and

```
select count(*)
from tbl_fact
where stat = 1 and id = 16 and year(fact_date) in (select Distinct(year(fact_date)) from tbl_fact)
group by (year(fact_date))
go
```

i have records that taged with dates that for now i have dates from 2017 and 2018 so i need counts for each year. but the id=16 has only date tag of 2018 not 2017 so i get result as

```
eg: 15
```

how ever it should be like

```
eg: 0 //2017
    15 //2018
```

Comment: select Distinct(year(fact_date)) from tbl_fact output of this query ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method to get all years in the data -- even when they don't meet the conditions of the `where` clause -- is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select year(fact_date) as yyyy,
       sum(case when stat = 1 and id = 16 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_16
from tbl_fact
group by year(fact_date)
order by yyyy;
```

Comment: I love the Sum(Case...) structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the count and year in two columns by:

```
select 
     count(*) as [COUNT], 
     year(fact_date) as [Year]
from tbl_fact
where stat = 1 and id = 16
group by (year(fact_date));
```

or as one string

```
select 
     count(*) + ' // ' + year(fact_date) as [grouping]
from tbl_fact
where stat = 1 and id = 16
group by (year(fact_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST([CountPerYear] AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        + ' // ' + 
        CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM 
 (
    select   year(fact_date) [Year]
           , count(*)  [CountPerYear]
    from tbl_fact
    where stat = 1 and id = 16
    group by year(fact_date)
 )x
```