# convert sql query included case when then to entity frame work query

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to do the below query in my project with entity framework. This the query from SQL server

```
select sum(case when beef_dairy_stat = 1 and param_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ctn
from user_behave_fact 
group by (year(fact_date))
go
```

And this is what I tried :\

```
fee_ctn = db.user_behave_fact.Sum(x=> x.beef_dairy_stat == true && x.param_id == 16 ? 1 : 0).GroupBy(y => y.fact_date.Value.Year).Select(y => y.Count()).ToList();
```

I am not familiar with linq querying .... the above SQL server query gives me

```
eg: 0    //count for year 2017
    15   //count for year 2018
```

And why I needed that case when in my SQL query => [query to select count of records for each year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663898/query-to-select-count-of-records-for-each-year/48664013#48664013)

Comment: Shouldn't have used a `SELECT COUNT(*) ... where  beef_dairy_stat = 1 and param_id = 1` instead?

Comment: i tried ... i had a problem when one of my records does not have eg:2017 date tag and just added newly in 2018 and then it should also count among the all year recorded in the table ... i mentioned the link of that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse `GroupBy` and `Sum` in EF. You can also use a condition inside `Count` directly:

```
fee_ctn = db.user_behave_fact
    .GroupBy(y => y.fact_date.Value.Year)
    .Select(y => y.Count(x=> x.beef_dairy_stat == true && x.param_id == 16))
    .ToList();
```